# Replacing multiple letters in Array in java

Tags: java, android

Im making an app that makes Arabic letters tall(by adding this `ــــ` after each letter) so i have to replace every signle letter(about 24 letters).
I've created an array this way:

```
String sub ="ــــ";
String arabicLetters="ج@ح@خ@@ه@ع@غ@ف@ق@ث@ص@ض@ط@ك@م@ن@ت@ل@ب@ي@س@ش@ظ@ئ"; //Will be splitted by split("@")
  String arabicLettersArr[];
arabicLettersArr=arabicLetters.split("@");
```

Now i have done the array.

Here is the replacing function:

```
public void makeLettersTall(View v){

        String text = edt.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!text.equals("")){
            for(String letter: arabicLettersArr){           
                    text = text.replace(letter,letter+sub);
            }
            edt.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

The problem:

let's say that i entered the letter `ب`
so i expect it to be `بــــ` but what i get is `ــــــــبــــ`
it seems that this symbole `ــــ`
was added twice before letter and once after while i want to be added only once after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at your arabicLetters String, you can see you added '@@' almost at the end without a letter in between, therefore your code will also replace `''` with `____` what causes the `ــــــــبــــ` .

Comment: that  ```@``` took from me an hour trying find another way to do that function. But finally that's  my only problem tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding Arabic, I guess this should do the job:

```
private static void arabicLetters() {
        String sub ="ــــ";
        String arabicLetters="ج@ح@خ@ه@ع@غ@ف@ق@ث@ص@ض@ط@ك@م@ن@ت@ل@ب@ي@س@ش@ظ@ئ"; //Will be splitted by split("@")
        String[] arabicLettersArr=arabicLetters.split("@");
        StringBuilder outString = new StringBuilder();
        for(String letter: arabicLettersArr)
            outString.append(letter).append(sub);
        System.out.println("result: " + outString.toString());
}
```

The problem with your code is

```
text = text.replace(letter,letter+sub);
```

which replaces a charater globally, i.e. if the same character appears more than once, it will be extended by _____ more than once

Comment: The problem was the extra "@". OP wants to add "____" only for the arabic letters that exist on the text.

Comment: isn't this code will append all letters?.. anyway everything was fine. my problem was in the Arabic string where i added ```@``` Twice without any letter between them.